# Dart - Base64 string is not equal to python

Tags: python, dart

When I use Python to generate a `base64` string that will be used in the `raw key { 'raw': value }` `GMAIL API`, sending the email occurs perfectly.

But when I use Dart to generate the same `base64` string, the string is not the same as python and because of that I can not send the email because the GMAIL API tells me `message: Invalid value for ByteString`

The string that will be converted to base64 is:

```
var message = '''<html><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><head></head><body>Test</body></html>'''
```

Python code:

```
import base64

e = base64.urlsafe_b64encode('''<html><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><head></head><body>Test</body></html>''')
print(e)
```

result:

`PGh0bWw-PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iY29udGVudC10eXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTgiLz48aGVhZD48L2hlYWQ-PGJvZHk-VGVzdDwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw-`

Dart code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
var _bytes = utf8.encode('''<html><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><head></head><body>Test</body></html>''');
var _base64 = base64Encode(_bytes);
print(_base64);
```

result:

`PGh0bWw+PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iY29udGVudC10eXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTgiLz48aGVhZD48L2hlYWQ+PGJvZHk+VGVzdDwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+`

Note that the only difference is the `+` sign in the base64 string of the Dart, and the `-` sign in the base64 string of Python

How can I generate the same base64 python code, so I can send the email in the GMAIL API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart has a URL safe version of Base 64 encode, like Python.

Change

`var _base64 = base64Encode(_bytes);`

to

`var _base64 = base64UrlEncode(_bytes);`

Answer (score 5):

**You** explicit asked Python for replacing all + characters with - in the base64 encoded string, because you have used the `urlsafe_b64encode` variant! The documentation says:

> base64.urlsafe_b64encode(s)
>
> Encode bytes-like object s using the URL- and filesystem-safe alphabet, which substitutes - instead of + and _ instead of / in the standard Base64 alphabet, and return the encoded bytes. The result can still contain =.

If you want the same string as Dart produces, just use simply `encodebytes` for Python3 or `encode` for Python 2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. I like with Dart have the same string Python