# encoding an image to base64 string

Tags: dart, flutter

am trying to upload image from photo gallery in dart using the library [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker).. which is working fine ..

and then am trying to convert the selected image to bas64 string like this:

```
imageSelectorGallery() async {
    _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      // maxHeight: 50.0,
      // maxWidth: 50.0,
    );
    List<int> imageBytes = _image.readAsBytesSync();
    print(imageBytes);
    String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
    print('string is');
    print(base64Image);
    print("You selected gallery image : " + _image.path);
    setState(() {});
   }
```

but this keeps returning a not correct string .. for example:

> _9j_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_-AAEEpGSUYAAQEAAAEAAQAA_9sAQwACAQEBAQECAQEBAgICAgIEAwICAgIFBAQDBAYFBgYGBQYGBgcJCAYHCQcGBggLCAkKCgoKCgYICwwLCgwJCgoK_9sAQwECAgICAgIFAwMFCgcGBwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoK_8AAEQgFAAPAAwEiAAIRAQMRAf_EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC__EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYq

and this cannot be converted to image ..

where is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Why do you think this is not a correct string and what does "cannot be converted to image" mean exactly?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176811/dart-base64-string-is-not-equal-to-python

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i tried to convert it at http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image but got error and the image is not converted

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no this is not exactly what i need..

Comment: Please check my first comment.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i answered you in my first comment :) when trying to convert it online to image again .. it is not converted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only copied the first 1024 characters of the encoded string into the question. Maybe the `print` command truncated it. Also, the online tool seems to prefer (require?) the URL safe version, so as Günter says, use `base64UrlEncode`.

To confirm that the string you are using is roughly the right length, add 33%. That is, a 2k image would convert to a string roughly 2667 characters long.

Comment: yes i think the string wasn't printed completely .. tried to check in another way and it is converted correctly! thanks :)

Comment: @lamatat how does you check if image64 are ok?

Comment: I'm wondering why it even truncates it, makes a hell out of the debugging process. Thanks, Richard